# Check string value from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am haveing strange issue comparing string value. I have a value in SQL with type (nchar) this value equals "text". And I set this value to string variable x, after that I compared the string variable x with the word "text" .

The problem is it shows that x doesn't equal the value "text" even that when I add x value to label, it shows the word "text".

Here is my code:

```
string x;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
       "select column from text_table where  column = 'text'", sqlCon))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            x = reader["column"].ToString();

            if (x.Equals("text"))
            {
                // run code  
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text ="x doesn't equal text";
            }
```

when I use the code it always shos the message "x doesn't equal text" but it should run the code as the value of the string x is "text"

Comment: How you are reading the table value will be helpfull if you provide the code of that as well!!!!

Comment: @marcelo I did that check the code

Comment: `nchar` is a fixed length column. Check  tail blanks

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the "nchar" column type, which has a constant length. I am not sure, but trimming before comparison may solve your problem.

Try

```
x = reader["column"].ToString().Trim();
```

Also there is a Bug, I think: There is no "x" here in (`if (stat.Equals("text")`).

Comment: I added .Trim(); and it worked for me thanks, but I have question, if I used varchar insteade do I need to use .Trim(); ?

Comment: No. In that case, you don't need to trim results.

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
create table text_table (
col1 nchar(10) ); -- fixed length column
insert text_table(col1) values ('text');
```

Pay attention to col1+'1' expression

```
select col1, col1+'1' 
from text_table 
where col1 = 'text'
```

What is going on? sql-server really ignores trailing spaces e.g.

```
select 'OK' where 'text' = 'text  ';
```

returns 'OK'.
But c# doesn't ignore trailing spaces and your `if` is not true. 
What to do? 
Use `Nvarchar` in your db or trim db column with `String.Trim()` before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the `.Equals()` method with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Change your code to

```
if(x.Equals("text",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase){
 //Do something
}
```

Comment: I did this but still the same issue

Comment: @anatermj your `x` value is wrong then.  Check what you get from the database